# How to cope with the perfect collinearity problem in D-i-D model in Stata

Tags: stata, difference-in-difference

In the standard Difference-in-Difference model

$$y_{ist}=α+\gamma \cdot \text{treat}_s+\theta \cdot \text{post}_{t}+{\delta} \cdot \text{post}\times \text{treat}_{st}+\lambda_{t}+\epsilon_{ist}$$

The subscript $i$ designates the individual's achievement within a school, $s$ represented a cluster of students $i$, and $t$ represents the year of measurement. $y$ is the achievement.

My dataset is school-level longitudinal data. I am interested in whether the school reform (conversion to the academy ) have improved the school performance, samples are observed from year 2002 to 2009. But schools are converted to the academies in different years. The problem is when I run the regression the (post=1 & treat=1) drops out.

I think it is because if a school is not treated the post will always equal to 0. How can I fix this problem in Stata or I have understood the model wrong?

**ADDED**

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input long schid byte treatyear int(yrbecomeacademy year) byte(earlyconverters afterconversion)
2036905 -4 2006 2002 1 0
2036905 -3 2006 2003 1 0
2036905 -2 2006 2004 1 0
2036905 -1 2006 2005 1 0
2036905  0 2006 2006 1 1
2036905  1 2006 2007 1 1
2036905  2 2006 2008 1 1
2036905  3 2006 2009 1 1
2056905 -4 2007 2003 1 0
2056905 -3 2007 2004 1 0
2056905 -2 2007 2005 1 0
2056905 -1 2007 2006 1 0
2056905  0 2007 2007 1 1
2056905  1 2007 2008 1 1
2056905  2 2007 2009 1 1
2066906 -4 2009 2005 1 0
2066906 -3 2009 2006 1 0
2066906 -2 2009 2007 1 0
2066906 -1 2009 2008 1 0
2066906  0 2009 2009 1 1
2096905 -4 2006 2002 1 0
2096905 -3 2006 2003 1 0
2096905 -2 2006 2004 1 0
2096905 -1 2006 2005 1 0
2096905  0 2006 2006 1 1
end
```

The *earlyconverters* is equivalent to *treat* and *afterconversion* is equivalent to *post*.

By tabulation shows:

```
   schools |
      that |
 converted |
        to |
 academies |  observation occurs
 up to and |     after academy
 including |      conversion
      2009 |         0          1 |     Total
-----------+----------------------+----------
         0 |       244          0 |       244 
         1 |       388        184 |       572 
-----------+----------------------+----------
     Total |       632        184 |       816
```

My initial command is:

```
regress schstdks4_cappedpts i.year earlyconverters afterconversion earlyconverters#afterconversion
```

But I think this regression will suffer perfect collinearity. To overcome this problem I first dropped the covariate *earlyconverters*, but I still cannot get the result I want. By running:

```
regress schstdks4_cappedpts i.year earlyconverters#afterconversion
```

I can have coefficient before (earlyconverters==1 & afterconversion==1), but I am not sure if the coefficient still have a difference-in-difference interpretation.

**Explanation of the data structure:**

I have school-level overall student performance over years... the data was collected every year from 2002 to 2009 and there are 819 schools in this sample. Different schools convert to academies in different years, but if they didn't convert to academies up to 2009 they are not treated (earlyconverters==0). Suppose a school converted to an academy in year 2004, the school-level observed data in year 2002 and year 2003 will have (afterconversion==0) but from year 2004 to year 2009 the afterconversion status will be 1.

Comment: It shouldn't matter if the cross-over is staggered. Can you clarify the subscripts in your model? You have $\lambda_t$ twice. Can you include a cross-tabulation of treat/post/year?

Comment: @AdamO yes I have made changes to my question, hope you will find my question clearer.. thank you!

Comment: I'm still confused. The labels on your cross tabs do not make sense. How are the data structured: Do you have one row per school or student per year or per month? I need to know how many months schools were in academy status vs other and how had already received treatment or had not yet.

Comment: @AdamO sorry... I added the explanation of the data structure at the end... would that be helpful? basically, the original paper used the individual level data but I only have school-level on hand... I have to make some changes to the model to make the DiD estimates consistent with the one produced by the paper. I myself is very confused about what the subscripts should like...